# Cannot use GaussianProcessRegressor from scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian

Does anyone have similar problem with GaussianProcessRegressor?

I updated all packages but still I get error:

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
ImportError: cannot import name GaussianProcessRegressor
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn import gaussian_process
kernel = gaussian_process.kernels.RBF(50., (50., 50.))
gpr = gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, normalize_y=False)
```

import it in this way